# Add multiple variations to a product on woocommerce using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, woocommerce

My Scenario is simple:

I have Attributes: Size & Color with Variations: Size(Small,Medium,Large) & Color(Red,Blue)
I have add these attributes to a specific ProductID.

How I can add the variation (Small/Red)  to this ProductID on woocommerce using vb.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the code below. it's important to create an Async Sub for this code.
I add my code to the "btn_Product_Variations" button's Click event.

```
 Private Async Sub btn_Product_Variations_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Product_Variations.Click
           
            Dim VariationAttr As New WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.VariationAttribute With {
                .id = Attribute_Color_ID,
                .[option] = "Red"}
    
            Dim VariationAttr1 As New WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.VariationAttribute With {
                .id = Attribute_Size_ID,
                .[option] = "Small"}
    
            Dim lstIVariationAttr() As WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.VariationAttribute = {VariationAttr, VariationAttr1}
            Dim lstOfVariationAttr As List(Of VariationAttribute) = New List(Of VariationAttribute)(lstIVariationAttr)
    
            Dim ProductVariations As New WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Variation With {
                .attributes = lstOfVariationAttr}
    
            Dim result As New WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Variation
            result = Await wc.Product.Variations.Add(ProductVariations, ProductID)
            MsgBox("Done! New Product_Variation_ID=" & result.id.ToString)
    
        End Sub
```